# Priorities of different preferences in wiki

Tags: wiki, preferences, twiki

What are the priority order of the following preferences in wiki specifically twiki or foswiki.

1. Default Preferences
2. Web Preferences
3. Site Preferences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DefaultPreferences is overwritten by SitePreferences is overwritten by WebPreferences. You can read [more about preferences on foswiki.org](http://foswiki.org/System/Macros#Preferences).